# Quick Sort on a Linked List with a random pivot in C

Tags: c, sorting, random, linked-list, quicksort

I have spent a lot of time trying to work on this problem for a class and am at ends. I have found lots of resources regarding arrays and other ways of selecting a pivot but I am just at ends and am really going crazy here, any help would be so much appreciated you can not possibly imagine.

```
#include <stdlib.h>     /*and, malloc*/
#include <stdio.h>      /*printf*/


struct listnode {

    struct listnode *next;
    long value;
};

/*Finds length of list, which is usefull in selecting a random pivot*/
int ListLength (struct listnode *list)
{
    struct listnode *temp = list;

    int i=0;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        i++;
        temp=temp->next;

    }
    return i;
}

/*Prints list*/
void printList(struct listnode *list)
{   
    struct listnode *node;
    node=list;
    printf("\nList Values\n");
    while(node!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%2lo ", node->value);
        node=node->next;
    }
}
/*Creates a list of desired length*/
struct listnode *createList(int lengthOfList)
{
    long i; 
    struct listnode *node, *space;
    space =  (struct listnode *) malloc( lengthOfList*sizeof(struct listnode));
    for( i=0; i< lengthOfList; i++ )
    {  (space + i)->value = 2*((17*i+1)%lengthOfList);
       (space + i)->next = space + (i+1);
    }

    (space+(lengthOfList-1))->next = NULL;
    node = space;

    return node;
}

/*Prof Brass's test*/
void Brass_test(struct listnode *list)
{
    int i;
    printf("\nChecking sorted list\n");
    for( i=0; i < 100; i++)
    {  
        if( list == NULL )
        { 
            printf("List ended early\n"); exit(0);
        }
        if( list->value != 2*i )
        {  
            printf("Node contains wrong value\n"); exit(0);
        }
        list = list->next;
   }
   printf("Sort successful\n");
}

/*Selects a random pivot point*/
struct listnode *SelectPivot(struct listnode *list)
{

    int k, n, i = 0;
    n = ListLength(list);


    struct listnode *pivot=list;

    k=rand()%n;

    for (; i < k; ++i)
    {
        pivot=pivot->next;
    }

    return pivot;
}

// Sorts a list using quicksort algo with random pivot point
struct listnode *Quicksort(struct listnode *list)
{
    // Return NULL list
    if (ListLength(list) <= 1) return list;

    struct listnode *less=NULL, *more=NULL, *next, *endl, *temp=list;

    /*Select a random pivot point*/
    struct listnode *pivot = SelectPivot(list);

    printf("Pivot Value = %lo\n", pivot->value);



    /*Divide & Conquer*/
    while(temp != NULL)
    {

        next = temp->next;

        if(temp->value < pivot->value)
        {
            temp->next = less;
            less = temp;
        }
        else 
        {
            temp->next = more;
            more = temp;

        }
        temp = next;
    }



    less = Quicksort(less);
    more = Quicksort(more);

    // Merge
    if(ListLength(less)!=0)
    {       
        while(endl != NULL)
        {
            endl = less->next;
            less->next = more;
            more = less;
            less = endl;
        }

        return more;        
    }
    else 
    {


        return more;    
    }

}

int main(void)
{
    struct listnode *node;

    node = createList(25);

    printf("Unsorted List\n");
    printList(node);

    printf("\nSorted List\n");
    node =  Quicksort(node);


    printf("\nList Count node %d\n", ListLength(node));
    printList(node);

   /* Brass_test(node);*/




    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Quicksort on a linked list is a quixotic concept - it really isn't an appropriate algorithm for the data structure.  You're likely to do best converting the list to an array, sorting the array, and then rebuilding the list.  Anything else is going to be enormously slower than an ordinary QuickSort because QuickSort is predicated on O(1) access time to any arbitrary items in the array, and with a list you get O(N) access to arbitrary items in the list, so your O(N log N) QuickSort algorithm becomes O(N*N log N), which is worse than Bubble Sort, etc.

Comment: @Jonathan: Not true -- Quicksort's partition phase traverses all the elements in order.  So even if you need an extra O(N) per step to choose the pivot, its still O(N log N) overall for sorting lists.  It may still be the case that other sorts make more sense, due to having a lower constant factor.

Comment: @ChrisDodd Right, for linked lists, mergesort variants are easy to implement and faster than quicksort.

Comment: Well at least it does not use C++ ;-) But given the extra linear pass at the start, he could just as well have created a temporary array with pointers, sort that, and rebuild the list afterwards (again an extra pass). Probably faster and a lot more robust, IMHO. But the real problem: linked lists are beautiful, but if you ever need to sort them, you probably did something wrong in the first place. And: mergesort is *of course* much more natural for linked lists.

Answer (score 5):

So here is the the solution to the problem for those that are curious about the code. I included only the function its self and the helper functions.

Cheers,

```
#include <stdlib.h>     //rand, malloc
#include <stdio.h>      //print
#include <time.h>

struct listnode {

    struct listnode *next;
    long value;
};

//Finds length of list, which is usefull in selecting a random pivot
int ListLength (struct listnode *list)
{
    struct listnode *temp = list;
    int i=0;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        i++;
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    return i;
}

// Selects a random pivot point
struct listnode *SelectPivot(struct listnode *list)
{
    int k, n, i = 0;
    n = ListLength(list);
    struct listnode *pivot=list;
    k=rand()%n;  //
    for (; i < k; ++i)
    {
        pivot=pivot->next;
    }
    return pivot;
}

// Sorts a list using quicksort algo with random pivot point
struct listnode *Quicksort(struct listnode *list)
{
    // Return NULL list
    if (ListLength(list) <= 1) return list;
    struct listnode *less=NULL, *more=NULL, *next, *end, *temp=NULL;

    // Select a random pivot point
    struct listnode *pivot = SelectPivot(list);

    // Remove pivot from list
    while(list !=NULL)
    {
        next = list->next;

        if(list->value != pivot->value)
        {
            list->next=temp;
            temp = list;
        }
        list = next;
    }

    // Divide & Conq
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        next = temp->next;
        if(temp->value < pivot->value)
        {
            temp->next = less;
            less = temp;
        }
        else 
        {
            temp->next = more;
            more = temp;    
        }
        temp = next;
    }

    // Recursive Calls
    less = Quicksort(less);
    more = Quicksort(more);

    // Merge
    if(less != NULL)
    {
        end = less;
        while(end->next != NULL){
            end=end->next;
            }
        pivot->next=more;
        end->next = pivot;
        return less;        
    }
    else{
        pivot->next = more;
        return pivot;   
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem is with your merge code -- it reverses the `less` list while prepending it to the `more` list, which results in garbage.

Answer (score -1):

In case of applying quick sort, the best practice is always to take the FLOOR(n/2) As pivot